# JavaScript advanced function call

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and I don't understand style of writting JS code which I read. I know "old" way but I didn't found manual where is explained this style of create and calling JS function. "New way":

```
// object
var dog = {
    color: 'brown',
    size: 'big'
};

//function to write dog size
(function(dog) {
    return dog.size;
})(dog);
```

From JavaScript manual I know (old way):

```
function prinSize(dog) {
    return dog.size
}
console.log(prinSize(dog));
```

Please could send me a link to JS doc, where is explained why

- in JS code are on start and end of function brackets
- why is possible after declare of function write brackets with ***.(dog)*** and with this you actually call the function with argument ***dog***.

Comment: It's a [iife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), nothing new here

Comment: What you're doing isn't "old way" vs. "new way". You still write functions the same as you always have. That first thing is an [immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and is a function that runs immediately.

Comment: The first code doesn't do anything.

Comment: I do not understand the English "in JS code are on start and end of function brackets". Anyway, where did you see this "new style", which would be better called "meaningless, do-nothing style"?

Comment: @Juhana Not exactly -- it returns `dog.size` but then throws it away.

Comment: Yes, a.k.a. doesn't do anything.

Comment: I don't know why someone marked this question with minus. I didn't understand style of writing the function and answer like "iife" is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this better, consider an alternative way to write the number `1`:

```
(function() { return 1; })()
```

What this does is define a function which returns 1, then immediately executes it with the `()` following it, so the whole thing evaluates to the number 1.

Of course, there is no reason to do this, I might just as well write `1`.

So to do `1+2`, I could write

```
(function() { return 1; })() + function() { return 1; }()
```

(I don't need the parentheses around the second function, since it is in a position syntactically where it could only be an expression.)

In the same sense, your function

```
(function(dog) { return dog.size; })(dog)
```

is **exactly** equivalent to just writing `dog.size` to start with. I don't know where you saw this, but standing on its own, it is ridiculous in two ways: first of all, as I said it is the same as `dog.size`, and second, it does not DO anything with the resulting size--to actually DO anything with the result, you'd need to write

```
var size = function(dog) { return dog.size; }();
```

but again, you might as well just write

```
var size = dog.size;
```

There are plenty of good reasons to use these so-called "IIFEs", or immediately-invoked function expressions, including hiding information inside them, but this is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks for explain, I have never heard about IIFEs.